# package com.google.gson does not exist in visual studio code on linux

Tags: java, gson

I am working on a java project with visual studio code on Linux.
I've downloaded the jar file for gson and added to the referenced libraries.
Currently, when I try to compile the java file,
"package com.google.gson does not exist"
this shows up, ive tried javac -classpath and stuff, but it returns:
"error:  no source file" and
" bash: /gson-2.9.0.jar: Permission denied"
. plz help, i am so lost D:

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have the gson jar in the same folder as your sources/project so you should use a relative path for the classpath parameter of javac:

```
javac -classpath gson-2.9.0.jar ...
```

or

```
javac -classpath ./gson-2.9.0.jar ...
```

where . stands for the current directory where you are executing javac. Also be careful with the path to the source files. [Here](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/tools/using-javac-command) are some examples of using javac.